# Copied persistent live linux USB Stick does not work

Tags: linux, grub, clone, liveusb, persistence

I created with RUFUS tool on windows a persistent live linux usb stick with ubuntu 11.
Then I deleted some not necessary apps and added some new ones.

Then I did on a linux system(Debian) a diskdump of the whole stick while it was unmounted, (2 partitions) with dd and saved the output at a .img file.

Then I copied the image back to another stick, same manufacturer,  model, same size, everything same as the original stick.

I tried to boot with the copied/cloned stick, but it was not booting, it got stuck at grub loader prompt....

I checked the UUID's , it is same at original and copied stick at both partitions..

```
root@debian:/home/user# sudo blkid /dev/sdal
/dev/sda1: LABEL="LIVE-LINUX-" UUID="131F-0C71" BLOCK SIZE= 512" TYPE-"vfat" PARTUUID-"00affefe-01"
root@debian: /home/user# sudo blkid /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: LABEL="persistence" UUID="45245347-e61d-f249-b722-8a5e8775cf89" BLOCK SIZE-"4096" TYPE-"ext3" PARTUUID="00affefe-02"
```

Any idea what went wrong, and how I can fix it ?
Or alternative way to clone the original stick to another device ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The FS, blocksize and partuuid are different, so not quite the same. Do the same with Clonezilla, that should produce an exact copy of the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried in paralel with ddrescue, which gave the same result. The copied stick is working now.

Comment: Excellent :-) I have to look into `ddrescue` - I default to Clonezilla as the only time it's failed me so far is when I forgot what exactly I imaged :-D

Comment: Remember what the original `dd` command line was? For creating the backup and writing it to the new drive?

Comment: @Xen2050   The original dd commands was: (Without blocksize)
dd if=/dev/sdd  of=/media/USB/image.img   status=progress

and

dd if=/media/USB/image.img  of=/dev/sdd   status=progress

Comment: Nothing looks glaringly wrong there... weird it didn't work, unless it encountered an error or had an unseen alias/option added

Answer (score 1):

I searched in parallel, on the web for my problem. I found a hint regarding
ddrescue tool. At a linux host with two usb ports it can be copied
directly from block device to block device..

```
ddrescue /dev/sdb /dev/sdc --force
```

I don't know why it doesn't work with dd.